# UnityWebRequest(path, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET): how add a variable to the request to retrieve a specific mysql row?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I currently retrieve all data from db with my sql query below by sending request to server's php file.

I need to post to the php file a variable as criteria for this mysql request, e.g WHERE carName="Somecar" AND slice=3. How can I add the criteria to my request and can I continue to still use the UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET and the ToFileDownloadHandler below?

Current Unity request:

```html
Debug.Log("Retrieving existing data from server.");
        UnityWebRequest myWebRequest = new UnityWebRequest(path, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbGET);
        
        myWebRequest.downloadHandler = new ToFileDownloadHandler(new byte[64 * 1024], savePathWithFileName);
        yield return myWebRequest.SendWebRequest();
```

And php:

```html
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, carName, thisCarImg, i_width, i_heigth, i_depth, b_width, b_heigth, b_depth, f_depth, m_width, m_heigth, i_date, slope, slice, slopeName, sliceName FROM $myTable")
$stmt->execute();
```

The best I could think is adding php as an additional tag although the question is how to add a form to Unity's query - using the form received in php is a different matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add the parameters in path

eg. sample.php?Somecar=122&slice=1

This way you can achieve this unity input in API call to PHP on GET request, if you are using POST then you can use WWWForm class.

Comment: You shouldn't use WWWForm as it is deprecated.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi I know but he asking for GET request

Comment: Right but what's the alternative: if I need to both post and get data from the query - GET and POST - and not use @Dharmik's suggestion above, what do I use? using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("[path].php", formData); and IMultipartFormSection form and echo the result to pick up via www.downloadHandler.text?